# os.walk() in reverse?

Tags: python

When I run `os.walk()`, I get my results in alphanumeric order; starting from 0, ending at z.  Is it possible to reverse this?

So if I have 3 directories; `apple/`, `bananas/`, `pears/`,  I would want `pears/`, `bananas/` and `apples/` returned.

Obviously I could store all the dirs as a list and then `.reverse()` but that's going to take a long time.

Comment: because I'm working on a very large set of directories which are in numerical order and I want to see the highest numbers first.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all, [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) does not specify the order in which the directories are returned, so if I were you I wouldn't rely on the alphabetic order.

Having said that, you can choose the order in which the subdirectories are traversed by leaving [`topdown`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) set to its default value (`True`), and then sorting `dirs` in-place:

```
import os
top='/home/aix'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=True):
  print root
  dirs.sort(reverse=True)
```

That'll make `os.walk()` traverse the subdirectories in reverse lexicographic order of their names.

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) explains how this works:

> When `topdown` is `True`, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in `dirnames`; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to inform `walk()` about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes `walk()` again.

Comment: Thanks.  Read the docs before hand, but didn't realize that meant you could reorder on-the-fly.

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand that you can actually modify the `dirs` used by `os.walk`.
(At least unless you set `topdown=False` explicitly).

In particular, you can for example remove directories, or resort the list.

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startdir):
    dirs.sort(reverse=True)
    # Also remove dirs you do not need!
```

Should actually do the trick at no significant additional cost.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reverse a generator in any generic way. The only solution is to cast it to a sequence and that iterate over the sequence in reversed order. Later terms of a generator cannot necessarily be known until the earlier ones have been calculated.

The solution below uses *reversed*. Performance should be fine if the directory structure is not to deep.

```
import os

directory = '/your/dir/'
for root, dirs, files in reversed(list(os.walk(directory))):
    print root, dirs, files
```